# How to make a strings input not null

Tags: java, null

Im working on a code to output a time stamp on each line of print. But when I create a method for this it automatically makes the string null, and then prints the time stamp AND `null` with every line. How do I stop it from saying `null` but still printing the time stamp?

here is the code and the output:

```
System.out.println(printTimeStamp()+ " Enter something to write to file...Q to quit ");

private static String printTimeStamp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String printTimeStamp = null; 
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date(); {
    System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));}
    return printTimeStamp;
}
```

output:

```
2015-11-19 23:28:19.369
null Enter something to write to file...Q to quit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are setting the variable `printTimeStamp` to null by writing,

```
 String printTimeStamp = null;
```

So you are returning the `printTimeStamp` variable which has a null value and you are printing the date by the line,

```
System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

As you are using System.out.pritnln in your method you don't need to use return type for that method. You can change your method as below,

```
private static void printTimeStamp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String printTimeStamp = null; 
        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date(); 
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));


}
```

If you want to use the return type then you can change the method as below,

```
private static String printTimeStamp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date(); 
    String printTimeStamp =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(date.getTime());
    return printTimeStamp;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing `printTimeStamp` with null, and not assigning there after, and returning the same value.

Modify your method and assign value to variable `printTimeStamp`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(printTimeStamp()+ " Enter something to write to file...Q to quit ");
    }

    private static String printTimeStamp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String printTimeStamp = null;
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        printTimeStamp = timestamp.toString();
        return printTimeStamp;
    }
```

**output**

```
2015-11-20 10:07:28.279
2015-11-20 10:07:28.279 Enter something to write to file...Q to quit
```

Answer (score 1):

You returning `null` from method name as `printTimeStamp` as you have not assigned any value to variable named as `printTimeStamp`. It is declared as null, but not initiated.  Use following to assign value

`String printTimeStamp =new Timestamp(date.getTime());`

Answer (score 0):

modify your code as below

```
    private static String printTimeStamp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date(); 
            String printTimeStamp =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(date.getTime());
    return printTimeStamp;
}
```

As I understand from your code,you just wanted to make the printTimeStamp() to print the current datetime. So better use my way. Convert the current Date time using simpledateformat class and return the datetime in string format. Just create a method which return datetime in string format and call this method where ever you want.For example `System.out.println(printTimeStamp()+ " Enter something to write to file...Q to quit ");`

Answer (score 0):

In `printTimeStamp()` Instead of `String printTimeStamp = null;`, use  `String printTimeStamp = "";`

You added the null object to String in your main function.